# Deployment Project Properties

Tags: c#, deployment

I have several files in my application folder. I want older versions to be replaced with newer ones, except 1 file (x). I want x to be replaced ALWAYS regardless of versions.  Currently I have "DetectNewerInstalledVersion=true" and "RemovePreviousVersions=true" and certainly it's not working well for x. any suggestions? I dont mind if I have to replace ALL files Always regardless of versions to achieve what I want. how to do this?

Comment: Are these resource files part of the project? Are you deploying a clean build or just trying to change flat files on the fly?

Comment: Do you have the AssemblyInfo.cs configured to automatically increment the build numbers of the file on each build?  This is the only way that the compiler could determine which file is newer.  If the version is always 1.0.0.0 for both files, then the new files may not be copied over.  

// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] 
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

Answer (score 0):

If any of these files are binaries you should **never** deploy mixed binaries. ie; taking commonlibrary1.dll from build 3 and dropping it into you prod environment which currently has binaries from build 1. This is very bad practice. You should deploy on a clean sleight.

To accomplish the file copying just change each files properties in VS (which changes it in the project file). Right click the file, select properties, set "copy to output directory" to "copy if newer" for all but x. For x set that property to "always copy".

When you deploy just delete whats on the server and replace it with your builds output dir. If that output dir isn't cutting it (meaning you have to move a bunch of crap around by hand), I'd focus on improving the build script.

Comment: are you talking about "File INstallationa Properties" ? I dont see "copy to output directory"

Comment: @JohnRyann I'm sorry, my response may not be useful. This is in the project itself in VS2010 and typically applies to resource files. All files have the "copy to output directory" property. If you're talking about a dll or something that's the result of a build, it won't be there (moving those files should be done via the build script). Are you working with an installer? What is your process for putting these files on the server?